# Optimize jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've a lot of `checkboxes`, like:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
...nearly 1000
```

They can be placed in different places of the document.

Using **jQuery** I replace each checkbox with the following:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

This is needed for customization.

Then, I bind some events to the parent div and a checkbox, like:

```
input.on('keyup keydown keypress click', function(e) {
    ...
});

div.on('click mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

And I get a nearly **5 seconds freeze time on page load.**

If I remove event bindings, everything works fine. So the tightest place here is events.

I've tried to use nearly this:

```
parent.on('keyup keydown keypress click', input, function(e) {
    ...
});

or 

$(document).on('keyup keydown keypress click', input, function(e) {
    ...
});

or

input.delegate('keyup keydown keypress click', function(e) {
    ...
});

...and some different ways of bindings
```

But none of them help (some are buggy and don't work as expected).

I've also read some articles about the event delegation, but don't have a reliable solution yet.

So the leak here is the number of events and bindings. 1000 elements = ~7000 event bindings and so on.

**How can I optimize this code to work without the freeze time on page load?**

Comment: I doubt their is a fix for this unless you reduce the amount of checkboxes. It's just too much binding for the browser. Are these checkboxes being dynamically added?

Comment: I also doubt that you need to bind `keyup`, `keydown` and `keypress` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "delegating it up" as much as possible, e.g.

```
$('body').on('keyup keydown keypress click', 'input', function (event) {
    // ...
});
```

If you're using jQuery < 1.7, use `delegate` instead:

```
$('body').delegate('input', 'keyup keydown keypress click', function (event) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.`
You could write this with `.on()` as follows: `$('body').on('keyup keydown keypress click', 'input',  function(event) {/* ... */});`

Comment: I'm using on(), so no difference?

Comment: how could `delegating it up as much as possible` improves the performance ?!!